# Using DVI instead of VGA: increase computer monitor resolution?

Tags: resolution, vga, dvi

This is for a computer screen. Both my video card and computer screen have DVI ports on them but I'm using VGA. I'm wondering if there would be a difference if I switched from VGA to DVI. My current resolution is 1920x1080 with the VGA cord.

1. Would my resolution increase if I were to switch to DVI? Are there any advantages of switching from VGA to DVI?
2. I've read there are 5 different type of DVI cables. how do I know which one to buy?

Comment: Digital DVI is far superior to analog VGA. Also, the best looking resolution is to use the maximum your screen can support. In this "native" scenario, you are matching pixel to pixel and there is no stretching, averaging, scanning, zooming or approximation of the image.

Answer (score 1):

DVI allows higher resolutions than VGA. Its also a digital signal, rather than analog, so its not prone to interference. To determine what type you need, compare the back of the monitor with this chart:

http://blog.123inkcartridges.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/DVI-types.gif

Most likely, you need DVI-D Single Link. Dual link will work as well, as long as it will plug in, and will make it so you don't have to swap the cable if you get a higher resolution monitor in the future.